# How do I tell that I have a multiple object result in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following function.

```
function Get-MultipleData 
{
  Get-Date
  'Hello'
  1+4
}

$date, $text, $result = Get-MultipleData

"The date is $date"
"The text was $text"
"The result is $result"
```

I know it returns 3 different objects that can be worked with.  If I just do
    $res = Get-MultipleData

How can I examine the $res object and figure out that there's 2 more objects associated with that result?

Update 8 Aug 2014:

here's a different function that shows this issue I have even better:

```
function query-DB {
  param ($query, $db) 
  $OpenStatic = 3
  $LockOptimistic = 3
  $RecordSet=new-object -comobject ADODB.Recordset
  $RecordSet.Open($Query, $db, $OpenStatic, $LockOptimistic)
  $RecordSet
  $Recordset | select -expandproperty Source
}
```

This points to an Access DB.

If I call this `$outinfo = query-db "select * from tb" $accessDBconnection`

I get this result:

```
Properties       : System.__ComObject
AbsolutePosition : 1
ActiveConnection : System.__ComObject
BOF              : False
Bookmark         : 512
CacheSize        : 1
CursorType       : 1
EOF              : False
Fields           : System.__ComObject
LockType         : 3
MaxRecords       : 0
RecordCount      : 1088
Source           : select * from tb
[...]
```

I don't see a way to get the connection string back.   If I do

```
$outinfo, $str = query-db "select * from tb" $accessDBconnection
```

Now I get out both objects easily enough.

How can I tell what those multiple objects are from a call like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can often be simplest to use `foreach-object` as suggested by miltonb which avoids the need to enumerate directly.

If you do need the number though, then the `count` property cannot be relied upon. This is because functions cannot be relied upon to return arrays. If a function tries to return an array containing a single member, then it is 'flattened' and the single member is returned instead. If the member is a simple string, then `count` will not be present.  So - if `object.count -eq $null` then you have a single value.

There are a couple of accepted ways of handling this:

Method 1 - force the result to be an array e.g.

```
$result = @( get-multipledata )
write-host $result.count
```

Method 2 - use `measure-object`

```
$result = get-multipledata
write-host ( $result | measure-object ).count
```

For chapter and verse on 'flattening', see Keith Hill's article:

http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/09/24/effective-powershell-item-8-output-cardinality-scalars-collections-and-empty-sets-oh-my/)

Answer (score 1):

miltonb is correct if you are returning multiple items and just want to iterate through them. In your example, it seems more like you want to return multiple items of different types and access them explicitly.

In this case, I think it makes more sense to return a custom PSObject with the named properties you want.

```powershell
function Get-MultipleData 
{
  $returnObj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Date = (Get-Date)
    Greeting = 'Hello'
    Result = (1+4)
  }

  $returnObj
}

$obj = Get-MultipleData

"The date is $($obj.Date)"
"The text was $($obj.Greeting)"
"The result is $($obj.Result)"
```

If you wanted to return multiple objects, you could do so, and then you would simply use `foreach` or `ForEach-Object` to iterate through the returned object(s).

Comment: I have no control over the get-multipledata function.   All I know is I get multiple non-related objects back.  They are different objects from what I can tell.

Comment: I see; in that case you should go with andyb's answer. If the values are all different types, you could test for the data type of each object with `$obj.GetType()` and use that to determine which ones were returned.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `foreach` which only iterates on things that exist.  And the Count property should tell you how many there are:

```
Write-Host $res.Count
foreach ($obj in $res){
   Write-Host $obj
}
```

Another approach would be to use the `foreach-object` command.

```
get-multipledata | foreach-object { <your processing here> }
```

Comment: The `count` property is only present on array/collection objects and will return $null rather than 1 for a single item.